# What sort of questions can I ask/answer with an Underworld Lore roll?

Tags: skills, pathfinder-2e, knowledge-check

been a while since I've been here last, but this question is a tad important.

I started playing in a ***Pathfinder 2e*** campaign a couple months ago with my character having the **Criminal** background. As such, I automatically gained the skill **Lore: Underworld** as well as **Expert Smuggler** (which isn't important for this question). Getting back on track, we just hit Level 3 today and I decided to take the **Unmistakable Lore** feat to somewhat guarantee that I'm gaining correct-enough information whenever I try to Recall Knowledge with a Trained Lore skill. Cooking Lore is fairly self-explanatory, but **I'm having trouble figuring out the types of things I should or shouldn't be able to glean know with Underworld Lore. Can someone please break it down for me?**

Answer (score 5):

Lore skills are described as *You have specialized information on a narrow topic.* The examples in CRB p 247-248 are not too exact, but as a summary it means that you know things about the topic. Pretty vague, huh? As usual, it all comes down to what your GM agrees. Still, there are lots of topics your character might be able to know about.

For underworld lore, some reasonable topics would be names of significant organisations, such as thieves guilds and crime syndicates. Names of famous or notorious criminals belong into this category too. Histories about remarkable crimes too. The story of a burglar who climbed the tower of the elephant? You know all the details of that glorious heist!

The more familiar the character is with the location, the more accurate information could be available. If one sails to far-away port, one shouldn't expect to know the name of the local cutpurse club without research. Then again, if the far-away port is Port Peril the pirate city, it should be reasonable that one has heard tall tales and some true ones about it too.

What kind of crime is (not) allowed would be another an example. Maybe there's a rule about honesty among thieves in one city, whilst in another a region it's a dog-eat-dog situation. One could try and recall if cutting purses on the market is allowed. There might, after all, be a protection racket. Getting caught by racket's thugs would be much worse from the city guard. In one place, petty theft is OK, but big time larceny is guild members only.

Underworld lore might also provide clues how to connect with shady people and how to deal with them. Maybe there are symbols akin to the hobo code that direct to fences and whatnot. What would be a market rate for fence's services? Who should be paid money to make that wanted -poster disappear? One needs some seals and signatures to an official document, so who's the scribe that moonlights as forger? How much is one expected to pay to guards so they look the other way? As an expert smuggler, you would likely to know a lot about greasing palms and fake signatures.

Underworld lore isn't all about how to benefit from crimes. It also is useful when fighting the underworld. "Round Up The Usual Suspects" requires one to know which people are to be gathered and where do they hang around.

- You see a shell game and know how it works. You might be able to tell who's the cutpurse and who are the shills in the crowd.
- There are people who seem too alert when one pays at the tavern. Do they seem to be muggers, cutpurses or worse?
- Two too friendly persons are buying drinks to a poor sap. Is the aim to help cheating in card game, press-ganging the mark, simply picking pockets or some more elaborate skullduggery?

Comment: You're making me want Underworld Lore. Great examples!